# Recursive function to print all numbers in ascending order up to the given entered number

Tags: java, recursion

I've got everything working for positive integers, but can't figure out how to do it with negative integers. It prints it from the biggest value to the smallest. I want it to be the same with the positive integers, from smallest value to biggest.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ascending {
public static void ascendingorder(int n){
if (n > 0) {
ascendingorder(n - 1);
System.out.print(n + " ");
}
        else if(n < 0){
        ascendingorder(n + 1);
                System.out.print(n + " ");
                }
}
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter an Integer Number: ");
        int n = in.nextInt();
        ascendingorder(n);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: that is, for a negative number, let's say `-4`, you do **not** want `-1 -2 -3 -4` but you want `-4 -3 -2 -1` ?!

Answer (score 0):

if I understood your question, the answer could be just to invert lines in the `else if` statement:

```
ascendingorder(n + 1);
System.out.print(n + " ");
```

So it would be

```
System.out.print(n + " ");
ascendingorder(n + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Same observation found you just need to write print statement first before calling recursion for negative integers

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In this case you function add 1 until n becomes 0. Then it prints valeue from 0 to n. In order to prevent it you should print n first then you shoud increase it's value.